# Idiomatic Kotlin for Level Order Traversal of BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, kotlin, binary-search-tree

Following is my implementation of Level Order Traversal of a BST:

```
fun levelOrder(): Iterable<Pair<Key, Int>> {
    class InternalNode(val node: Node<Key>, val level: Int)

    val yetToVisit = emptyQueue<InternalNode>()
    val visited = emptyQueue<Pair<Key, Int>>()

    root?.also { yetToVisit.enqueue(InternalNode(it, 1)) }

    while (!yetToVisit.isEmpty) {
        do {
            val node = yetToVisit.dequeue().also { visited.enqueue(it.node.key to it.level) }
            listOf(node.node.left, node.node.right)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map { InternalNode(it!!, node.level + 1) }
                    .forEach(yetToVisit::enqueue)
        } while (!yetToVisit.isEmpty && yetToVisit.peek().level == node.level)
    }

    return visited
}
```

I'm wondering if the above can be implemented in a more idiomatic/functional manner without using `while` and `do-while`. Ideas?

Comment: It's recommended to use `filterNotNull` instead of `filter(Objects::nonNull)`, which will prevent you from using `!!` operator in the next map operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using a `sequence` (say, `generateSequence`):

```
fun levelOrder(): Iterable<Pair<Key, Int>> {
    class InternalNode(val node: Node<Key>, val level: Int)

    val yetToVisit = emptyQueue<InternalNode>()
    val visited = emptyQueue<Pair<Key, Int>>()
    fun peek() = yetToVisit.dequeue()
            .also { visited.enqueue(it.node.key to it.level) }

    root?.also { yetToVisit.enqueue(InternalNode(it, 1)) }
    if (yetToVisit.isEmpty) return visited
    generateSequence(peek()) { node ->
        if (!yetToVisit.isEmpty && yetToVisit.peek().level == node.level) peek()
        else null
    }.forEach { node ->
        listOfNotNull(node.node.left, node.node.right)
                .map { InternalNode(it, node.level + 1) }
                .forEach(yetToVisit::enqueue)
    }

    return visited
}
```

And BTW you may use `listOfNotNull` or `listOf().filterNotNull` to replace `filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Note I've just syntaxically refactored your code but since I cannot compile your code I can't verify the correctness of it. If it's not working as expected please leave a comment.

Comment: Your code won't compile since the variable `node` in `generateSequence` isn't defined.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Fixed

Comment: Your code isn't the same logic as mine and fails the traversal test. I suggest running it before suggesting further (incorrect) solutions.

Comment: Because I don't know how `peek`, `enqueue` and `dequeue` are implemented. I guess `dequeue` is `pop` and `enqueue` is `add` and wrote the code above. Edited a little